# Build a Hashset from a lines iterator

Tags: rust

I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

let test = "foo\nbar\n";

let hashset: HashSet<_> = test
    .lines()
    .collect::<Result<HashSet<_>, _>>()
    .unwrap()
```

I get this error:

> a value of type `Result<HashSet<_>, _>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&str`

I tried to use an intermediary `Vec` but I didn't succeed either. I understand the error but I don't know how to elegantly fix this

This works but isn't the fastest solution:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

let test = "foo\nbar\n";
let hashset = HashSet::new();

for word in test.lines() {
  hashset.insert(p.to_string());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `lines()` method cannot fail, as it operates over a `&str`, therefore you should collect to a `HashSet<&str>`.
See https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines.

For example:

```
let test = "foo\nbar\n";

let hashset: HashSet<&str> = test
    .lines()
    .collect();
```

See it in action in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=077bb2b1c45f13c92f93e100d300539b).

Your confusion here seems to come from the fact that there's a similar `lines` method that operates on `BufRead` which can fail due to operating on files, or other I/O based sources.

See https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines.

Apart from this difference, `BufRead.lines` varies as it yields owning `String`s instead of borrowed `&str`.

If you want to create a HashSet which owns its contents, you can modify your code as this:

```
let test = "foo\nbar\n";

let hashset: HashSet<String> = test
    .lines()
    .map(String::from)
    .collect();
```